# How do I use a Tascam DP-32SD as a midi controller?

Tags: recording

I had a Tascam 2488 port-a-studio that had MIDI capability. I now have a Tascam DP-32SD with no MIDI capability. How do I use my Tascam DP-32SD as a midi controller?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you don't. It does not have midi capability, so it cannot be used as a midi controller.

If you need a midi controller you'll need to buy one.